# If-statement and switch problems

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a game in which a user would input their wager with the spinner provided then select one of the radio buttons cold or hot. These radio buttons are based on the color wheel colors that are either cold (purple green blue) or hot (yellow, red, orange). These colors are saved as images in my array and the color is selected randomly and will appear in an invisible panel that is made visible once you hit the play button. Your wager is taken and depending on the amount it is either doubled, tripled, or quadrupled. If the color is white or black the house would win and the user would receive no money, same goes for if they chose cold and the color was hot and vice versa. The problem I'm encountering is when playing the game I keep winning even though the color is cold and I chose hot or if the color is hot and I chose cold I do not see where the bug and need some help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HotAndColdGUI extends JFrame
{
    private SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 10, 100, 10);
    JSpinner bet = new JSpinner(sm);
    private JButton replay = new JButton("Play Again");
    private JRadioButton Hot = new JRadioButton("Hot", false);
    private JRadioButton Cold = new JRadioButton("Cold", false);
    private JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    private JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    private ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    private JPanel color = new JPanel();
    private int moneyEarned;
    private static String[] imageList = { "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\red.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\orange.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\yellow.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\blue.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\purple.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\green.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\white.jpg", "C:\\Users\\Joe\\HotAndColdFastGambling\\Images\\black.jpg" };

    public HotAndColdGUI(int width, int height)
    {
        super("HotAndColdGUI");

        setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        Panel bPanel = new Panel();
        JLabel betLabel = new JLabel("Bet:");
        bPanel.add(betLabel);
        bPanel.add(bet);
        bPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(bPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        bPanel.setVisible(true);

        Panel hcPanel = new Panel();
        Hot = new JRadioButton("Hot");
        Cold = new JRadioButton("Cold");
        group.add(Hot);
        group.add(Cold);
        hcPanel.add(Hot);
        hcPanel.add(Cold);
        hcPanel.add(play);
        hcPanel.add(replay);
        hcPanel.add(exit);
        hcPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(hcPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        hcPanel.setVisible(true);
        play.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        exit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        ImageIcon image;
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        int colorNumber = (int) (8 * Math.random() + 1);
        image = new ImageIcon(imageList[colorNumber]);
        label.setIcon(image);
        color.add(label);
        JTextField winningsField = new JTextField();
        winningsField.setEditable(false);
        bet.getValue();
        String Sbet = bet.getValue() + "";
        int wager = Integer.parseInt(Sbet);
        if (wager >= 100)
        {
            moneyEarned = wager * 2;
            winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");

        }
        else if (wager >= 50)
        {
            moneyEarned = wager * 3;
            winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");

        }
        else if (wager <= 50)
        {
            moneyEarned = wager * 4;
            winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");

        }
        if (Hot.isSelected())
        {
            switch (colorNumber)
            {
                case 4:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (Cold.isSelected())
        {
            switch (colorNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    moneyEarned = wager * 0;
                    winningsField.setText(moneyEarned + "");
                    break;
            }
        }

        JLabel pwinnings = new JLabel();
        if (moneyEarned == 0)
        {
            pwinnings.setText("Sorry, You Lost!");

        }
        if (moneyEarned > 0)
        {
            pwinnings.setText("You've won: $");
        }
        color.add(pwinnings);
        color.add(winningsField);
        color.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(color, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        color.setVisible(false);

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == play)
            {
                color.setVisible(true);

            }
            if (e.getSource() == exit)
            {
                dispose();
            }
            if (e.getSource() == replay)
            {

            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new HotAndColdGUI(1366, 768);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to diagnose the problem when you throw a whole chunk of code? Post the section which is giving you issues so that we can narrow down the problem :)

Comment: That's the problem I can't find the part that is giving the problem, otherwise I would have never even came here :)

Comment: Then there's most probably an issue with your logic in the code based on how you really need it to be

Answer (score 1):

you keep wining because you never actually "Play"

When you make your GUI you first put a value in moneyEarned and then you go to your switch
but at construction of your GUI both your checkboxes are not selected.

So both hot.isSelected and cold.isSelected are false.
This means your moneyEarned is not set to 0 and you always win.